# Understanding differences in Coefficients between Multivariate OLS, PLS and Ridge-Regression when having Multicollinearity

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, multivariate-testing

*Hello Guys, I’m new in python and i have a problem with a multicollinearity inside a multivariate Regression Model.*

I have date of two Conveyor Belts one after the other with ‘load’ ‘speed’ ‘Energy’ and so on per hour. I want to understand the Energy performance. First, I tried a normal Ordinary least squares Model to get Coefficients. But I could also see that the coeffs are different between the conveyors. The point is that one of the belts is a few meters smaller and it has a to bring the load a few meters up ways. I calculated a slope of 0.09. Now I want to get information about it. So, I put a separate Column in every belt and append them. I did a Ridge regression about it knowing, when alpha is zero I have the **OLS** regression again. But the Coefficients I get now are surprising. Like before Load has a big influence and even the new slope as expect, but the speed of the belt has now negative impact of the Energy performance. It would be great but cannot be possible, that when the speed of the engine increases the energy decrease…

In my opinion it could be a result of multicollinearity. So i used a Correlation Matrix but between Slope and Speed are no correlations. So I tried to do a Partial least squares but the coefficients I get there are near zero but on the other hand the **PLS** Model give me back X and Y_loading with values i expect as my Coefficients would look like.

I know that **PLS** estimated the Coefs by `y = x*coef +ERR`.

I want to know if there is a possibility to get the ERR values? Can it be that an ERR Value are too big to get “good” Coefficients? 
Is it possible to get much lower Coefficients by PLS than OLS ? What are the y_loadings Values inside the PLS Model? 
and is there another model you would use to check Energy performance? 
Thanks for your help.

```
##########  Partial Least Square Regression ######

PLSRegr = PLSRegression(n_components=2)
pls = PLSRegr.fit(X_train, Y_train)
pls_pred = pls.predict(X_test)

pls_meanSquaredError = mean_squared_error(Y_test, pls_pred)
print("PLS MSE:", pls_meanSquaredError)
pls_rootMeanSquaredError = sqrt(pls_meanSquaredError)
print("PLS RMSE:", pls_rootMeanSquaredError)

pls_mean = mean_absolute_error(Y_test, pls_pred)
print("PLS Mean_absolute Error:",pls_mean)

pls_r2 = r2_score(Y_test,pls_pred)
print("PLS R²", pls_r2)

print('PLS Coefficients: \n', PLSRegr.coef_)
print('PLS loadings: \n', PLSRegr.y_loadings_)
print('PLS loadings: \n', PLSRegr.x_loadings_)



##### Ridge Regression 

n_alphas = 10
alphas = np.logspace(-1.5, 2.5, n_alphas)


coefs = []
errors = []
error_pred = []
Rsquared = []
Rsquared_pred = []
scores = []
p = 6 # Number of Predictors
N = 14266 # Total sample Size


for a in alphas:
    ridge = KernelRidge(alpha=a, kernel='linear', coef0=0)

    ridge.fit(X_train, Y_train)

    KRR_pred = ridge.predict(X_train)   # Prediction Train
    rgr_pred = ridge.predict(X_test)    # Prediction Test
    print(KRR_pred)
    print(ridge.dual_coef_)

    print(np.dot(X_train.transpose(),ridge.dual_coef_))
    coefs.append(np.dot(X_train.transpose(),ridge.dual_coef_))

    Rsquared.append(ridge.score(X_train, Y_train))
    print("R² of Trainset:",Rsquared)

    Rsquared_pred.append(r2_score(Y_test,rgr_pred))
    print("R² of Prediction:", Rsquared_pred)

    Rsquaredadj = 1 - (((1-(r2_score(Y_test,rgr_pred)))*(N-1))/(N-p-1))
    print("Adj R²",Rsquaredadj)

    errors.append(mean_squared_error(ridge.dual_coef_,KRR_pred))
    errors2.append(mean_squared_error(ridge.dual_coef_,rgr_pred))   
    print('MSE of bias:', errors)

    error_pred.append(mean_squared_error(Y_test, rgr_pred))
    print("RGR MSE:", error_pred)

    mse = np.mean((rgr_pred - Y_test) ** 2)
    print("MSE check", mse)

coefs = np.array(coefs)
coefs = coefs.reshape(n_alphas, 6)
print('Coefficients: \n', coefs)
print('Alphas: \n',alphas)
print(KRR_pred)
print(ridge.dual_coef_)
```

> Temp, Load, Tension, speed, Slope
>
> PLS Results :  0.00, 0.11, -0.01, 0.02, 0.04
>
> OLS/Ridge(Alpha=Zero) Results: -0.038,1.37,-0.067,-0.11,0.33
>
> OLS Result without slope:  -0.011, 1.11, -0.33, 0.40

I expect values like `without slope` but "smaller" in Ridge with positive `speed` Coefficient and higher results in **PLS**